# IE8 and below conditional formatting

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a web page (see http://goo.gl/Bfnm6) at the bottom of which appear two circles. For non-IE browsers (and also IE if version > 8), the circles are produced by CSS. For IE8 and below, the circles are rendered as .PNG files because these browsers cannot generate the circles using CSS.

My problem is that although my conditional formatting correctly serves the .PNG files when IE8 or below is found, the Javascript which should then be called to remove the div's containing the CSS-generated circles doesn't remove the div's. The result is that you see the artifacts in the screenshot below. The artifacts are the text contained within the div's that in turn contain the CCS declarations. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried the following, but in all cases the artifacts remain:

1. use jQuery to call `.empty()` on the div's as you see in the code block below
2. set the div's inner HTML to "" by using plain Javascript to call `document.getElementById("advisers-css-image").innerHTML=""` and `document.getElementById("industry-css-image").innerHTML=""`
3. Call `document.getElementById("advisers-css-image").style.visibility="hidden"` and `document.getElementById("industry-css-image").style.visibility="hidden"`

**Screenshot**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<div class="advisers display-inline-block">
<a href="#" id="advisers-png-image">
  <img src="images/advisers220x220.png?format=300w" alt=""> 
</a>
</div>

<div class="display-inline-block">
<a href="#" id="industry-png-image">
  <img src="images/industry220X220.png?format=300w" alt="">
</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#advisers-css-image" ).empty();
$( "#industry-css-image" ).empty();
$( "#advisers-circle-text" ).empty();
$( "#industry-circle-text" ).empty();
</script>
<![endif]-->

<a href="#" id="advisers-css-image">
  <div id="advisers-circle-text "class="circle display-inline-block hovershadow advisers advisers-box-shadow text">Professional
    advisers</div>
</a>

<a href="#" id="industry-css-image">
  <div id="industry-circle-text"class="circle display-inline-block hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
</a>
```

Comment: if you're using jQuery why not just do something like `$('#advisers-css-image, #industry-css-image').remove();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Scott pointed out, the problem is that your scripts are executing before the HTML is rendered. You can move the script to above the HTML, or execute it at DOM-ready.

This should do the trick:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#advisers-css-image, #industry-css-image').remove();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Zach, a very neat solution. I'm a server-side guy who's having to get down and dirty with UI - respect to all of you guys!

Answer (score 3):

It because the links need to be above the script in the conditional formatting.  At the time the script executes the links haven't been rendered yet.

So move them up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="advisers-css-image">
  <div id="advisers-circle-text "class="circle display-inline-block hovershadow advisers advisers-box-shadow text">Professional
    advisers</div>
</a>

<a href="#" id="industry-css-image">
  <div id="industry-circle-text"class="circle display-inline-block hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
</a>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<div class="advisers display-inline-block">
<a href="#" id="advisers-png-image">
  <img src="images/advisers220x220.png?format=300w" alt=""> 
</a>
</div>

<div class="display-inline-block">
<a href="#" id="industry-png-image">
  <img src="images/industry220X220.png?format=300w" alt="">
</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#advisers-css-image" ).empty();
$( "#industry-css-image" ).empty();
$( "#advisers-circle-text" ).empty();
$( "#industry-circle-text" ).empty();
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

---

Or as @Zach L says in the comments, you could wrap your conditional formatting script in a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.  Doing so, you wouldn't need to alter your markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $( "#advisers-css-image" ).empty();
        $( "#industry-css-image" ).empty();
        $( "#advisers-circle-text" ).empty();
        $( "#industry-circle-text" ).empty();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Or he could wrap the JS in a `$(document.ready(function(){...});`

Comment: Thank you Scott - I accepted Zach's answer because (as far as I can determine, not entirely clear) his answer was posted a little sooner, but I've upvoted yours too because it works - thank you for your time!

Comment: @ClivevanHilten - Yea, mine was about 5 minutes prior to his, but I don't mind at all. Glad you got things working.

Comment: I can confirm, Scott did it first ;-) kudos!